# Vim: match next/previous line in search pattern

Tags: vim

I'm trying to practice my search patterns for ex commands and trying to do stuff I would usually do with macros using them, and I got stuck with one I'm not sure is possible.

I have some code that looks like this:

```
public myFunc (): any {
    return {};
}
```

And I'm trying to yank it with this command (with the cursor after the function):

`:?\vpublic\s*\w+\s*\(.*\)\s*:\s*\w+\s*\{?;/}$/y`

This works as expected and matches the function that I mentioned up there.

What I would like to do but haven't found a way is to ignore the first line and the last one (I just want the contents of the function). I suspect it is possible to do it somehow (maybe +/- search offsets?), but I haven't had any luck yet.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a simple matter of adding the appropriate *offsets* (`:help search-offset`). You basically define a range with two searches (one upwards from the current position, one downwards from there): `?...?;/.../`. To exclude the targets, you just add / subtract 1; this is done by appending the offset to the search: `?...?+1;/.../-1`. Applied to your example:

```
:?\vpublic\s*\w+\s*\(.*\)\s*:\s*\w+\s*\{?+1;/}$/-1y
```

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind but I couldn't get the syntax right, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To insert carriage return (Enter) like below use `Ctrl-v Enter`

```
:normal ?public^Mjwyiw
```

Explanation

```
:normal  ............ in normal mode
?public ............. search backward for public
^M .................. Enter
j ................... move to the line below
yiw ................. yank inner word
```